# How to use a variable as an image src - vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vue and done a little bit of html and css, i want to use a variable as the image directory but the image never loads, the variable is being updated by a tauri function which works and i need the image to change as well.

this is a bit of my code

```html
<template>
<img v-bind:src=getimg()>

   -- and --

<img :src = {{data}}}>

   -- and --

<img src = {{data}}>

   -- and much more ... --
</template>

<script setup>
var data = ref("./assets/4168-376.png")

function getimg() {
    console.log(data1.value)
    return require(data1.value)
}
</setup>
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on your code, you are using Vue3 Composition API. There are a few things that are missing from your code that probably didn't made your app work.

1. As others have mention, you don't use curly braces in the attributes. You use

```html
<img :src="variable"> // just use : in front of an attribute and it will consider as v-bind
<img v-bind:src="variable"> // or you directly use v-bind, less commonly used
<img :src="'static string'"> // no point doing this, but just a reference of how it works
```

2. When you are using composition API, you will have to import the functions first such as `ref`.

```html
<template>
  <img :src="data">
  <img v-bind:src="data">
  <img :src="getimg()">
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const data = ref("./assets/4168-376.png") // prefer const over var cus this variable will never be reassigned

function getimg() {
   // why are you using data1.value tho? It should be data.value
   // also i don't think 'require' is needed here 
   return require(data1.value) // i just copy paste from your code
}
</script>
```

**Extra**: when dealing with values that does not require a parameter, usually using `computed` will be better. Refer [Vue computed properties](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#computed-caching-vs-methods)

```html
<template>
   <img :src="data">
   <img v-bind:src="data">
   <img :src="getImg">
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue' // import it first

const data = ref("./assets/4168-376.png")

const getImg = computed(() => {
  return data.value
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without curly braces:

```
<img :src="data">
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the syntax is:

```
v-bind:src /*or :src */
```

And **not** `<img src = {{data}}>`.

Next, the bind data should be part of the [vue instance](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html). Otherwise on binding you get an **error**.

> Property or method 'getimg' is not defined on the instance but
> referenced during render.

Last, if you want to bind the value to a function you should run the function like this:

```
  <img :src="get_image()">
  <!-- Not   <img :src="get_image"> -->
```

#### Basic Snippet example (vue 2):

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    photo_path: "https://picsum.photos/id/237/111/111",
    
  }),
  methods: {
    get_image: function() {
      return "https://picsum.photos/id/237/111/111";
    },
  }
})

/* will not work */
function not_working(){
  return "https://picsum.photos/id/237/111/111";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<!-- Import Numeral.js (http://numeraljs.com/#use-it) -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/2.0.0/numeral.min.js"></script>
<!-- Then import vue-numerals -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-numerals/dist/vue-numerals.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <img :src="photo_path">
  <img :src="get_image()">
  <img :src="not_working">  
</div>
```

**v-bind docs:**

- https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-bind